# Bootstrap - top navbar with tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to incorporate tabular structure into my Bootstrap navbar.  Currently I have the following setup:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="navbar-brand">
            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
            <li><a href="#/menu1">MENU-ITEMS1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/menu2">MENU-ITEMS2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/menu3">MENU-ITEMS3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/menu4">MENU-ITEMS4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am getting my tabs vertically aligned on top, however I need them on the bottom of my navbar.

The following Bootply demonstrates the problem:
http://www.bootply.com/ouKLqFBeqj

Comment: Could'nt you just add `margin-top`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **Codepen** you can check out http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/rOVaKV

All ive done is incorporated a fix from the link i posted in the comment [Twitter Bootstrap: Align nav-tabs to bottom of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350253/twitter-bootstrap-align-nav-tabs-to-bottom-of-div)

Essentially all you need to do is add a `position:relative` class to the parent div of your tabs and then on your tabs list add 
`position:absolute;`
`bottom:0;`
and in your case i added `left:95` because of your navbar link